# Testing an angular controller that uses a service as dependencies

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Hello I have this service :

```
angular.module('angularProtoApp')
  .factory('ModelService',['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {

    var folder = 'assets/';
    var extension = 'Model.json';

    return {
      getModelFromJson : function (pageCode) {
       return $http({
         method : 'GET',
         url : folder + pageCode + extension,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
       }).then(
         function (response) {
           return response.data;
         }
       );
      }

    };
}]);
```

And I have this controller :

```
angular.module('angularProtoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'ModelService', function ($scope, $location, ModelService) {

   $scope.model = '';

   ModelService.getModelFromJson('Ffco').then(
     function (data) {
       $scope.model = data;
       if ($scope.model.isSeleniumTestRunning) {
         $scope.slnPageCodeClass = 'sln' + $scope.model.pageCode;
       }

       $location.path('/' + $scope.model.pageCode);
     },
     function (error){
       console.log(error);
     }
   );

  }]);
```

But I don't know how to correctly test the controller.
I began to do something like this, but I don't think this is enough.

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

 // load the controller's module
 beforeEach(module('angularProtoApp'));

 var MainCtrl,
   scope,
   ModelServiceMock;

 beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _ModelService_) {
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
   ModelServiceMock = _ModelService_;
   spyOn(ModelServiceMock, 'getModelFromJson').and.callThrough();
   $controller('MainCtrl', {
     $scope: scope,
     ModelService : ModelServiceMock
   });
 }));

 it('should call getModelFromJson method on ModelService', function () {
   scope.$digest();
   expect(ModelServiceMock.getModelFromJson).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
});
```

I'm not sure I test the service correctly, I did not succeed in testing the scope variables of the controller.

Does somebody know how to test it properly ?

Thanks.